# Angularjs - Convert <br/> into plain text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My text doesn't convert into plain text that contain `<br/>` html tag.

I want to be like this

```
Hi

I'm Nurdin !!
```

Not

```
Hi <br/> <br/> I'm Nurdin!!
```

html

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="" class="form-control" ng-model="rule.message" ></textarea>
```

js

```
xxxxxControllers.controller('MemberRuleUpdateCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    '$location', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http) {
        $scope.rule = {};
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://xxxxx.my/api/get_rule_details.php?ruleId=' + $routeParams.ruleId
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.rule = {
                message: data.rule[0].message
            };
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("No internet connection.");
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing the HTML formatting is being saved into your db/datasource displaying it as follows

`<div  ng-bind-html="rule.message" >` will obey the formatting.

You also need to include angular sanitize module into your project.

**EDIT**

After reading your question I again I think I misunderstood it a bit so here is a more detailed answer.

1. If you'd like to see how to display a HTML encoded string properly in a `div` take a look at this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/cPSfL8Y0WWpTVxWo4OyR?p=preview
2. If you would like to display HTML encoded string in a `textarea` while keeping formatting - that is not possible - textarea doesn't deal with HTML as far as I know.
3. If you  **still** want to display HTML encoded string in a 'textarea` with formatting you need to use something like this http://textangular.com/ - it replaces your textarea with a div that looks and behaves like textarea hence why it's able to display proper HTML formatting